# On append images are over written

Tags: html, css, masonry

I am appending images to a div tag, but the appended images are being overwritten by each other.

HTML

```js
var array = [{
    imageURL: "http://placehold.it/1920x1920",
    image_Title: "The Cycle",
    image_Description: "What makes the desert beautiful is that somewhere it hides a well.",
    importance: 3
  },
  {
    imageURL: "http://placehold.it/1920x1920",
    image_Title: "The Cycle",
    image_Description: "And, when you want something, all the universe conspires in helping you to achieve it",
    importance: 1
  }, {
    imageURL: "http://placehold.it/1920x1920",
    image_Title: "The leaf",
    image_Description: "All we are lost stars, trying to light up the dark",
    importance: 1
  }

]


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  str1 = ' <div class="grid-item" style="font-family: serif;height:33.3%;width:33.3%;"> <img src="' + array[i].imageURL + '">' + array[i].image_Description + ' </div>';

  if (array[i].importance == 1)
    str1 = ' <div class="grid-item" style="font-family: serif;height:66.6%;width:66.6%;"> <img src="' + array[i].imageURL + '">' + array[i].image_Description + ' </div>';
  $("#grid").append(str1);
}
```

```css
.grid {
  background: white;
}


/* clear fix */

. grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  border: solid 15px white;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: x-large;
  float: left;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="js/masonry-docs.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-left: 7%; margin-right: 7%">
  <div class="grid"></div>
```

The images that I am appending with JavaScript are overlapping with each other..I want the page to have a masonry layout.

Answer (score 0):

I am commenting here because i cannot comment in question yet. 
You are using `$("#grid").append(str1);` to append but in html you have class `<div class="grid"></div>`. So make them same first. 
Can you create fiddle to make it more easy to run and edit code?